# Landscape doesn't update all packages?

Tags: landscape

I'm running a personal Landscape server (latest from the 16.04 LTS repo) to monitor and deploy updates to a set of Ubuntu servers. The Landscape server itself and all the servers to monitor are all 16.04 LTS LXC containers on top of a Proxmox hypervisor.

I've noticed that Landscape seems to miss packages when it notifies about updates (both regular and security updates). I can for example get a notification about 5 available updates in landscape and apply them.

If I then `ssh` in to the machine once Landscape reports that all packages have been updated and do a manual `apt update` It can sometimes still report 5 available updates that gets deployed if I do an `apt upgrade`.

This happens regularly across all containers. Could this some kind of sync problem or something else?

Has anybody seen anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

This could be normal behavior, let me walk through a couple things.

1. Landscape clients only update package caches (`apt-get update`) 4 times per day.
2. Landscape servers only instruct clients to upgrade a **named selection** of packages.  Even if you click the "upgrade all packages" button.  It never runs `apt get [dist-]upgrade` or similar.  A specific set of upgrades are requested of the clients.

Combine these two things together, and there are certainly many timing windows available for you to ssh to a system after an upgrade job is finished and see more things to upgrade.

Next time you see this, hopefully these two bits of information would help explain things.  To dig deeper, you would need to collect.

- What packages did landscape claim to upgrade (names and versions)
- What packages were available to upgrade via ssh (names and versions)
- What times did each of these events happen.

Between that, and the publishing history of packages in the ubuntu archives (which is tracked on launchpad), you usually have enough data to explain these kinds of discrepancies.

See for example: [Publishing history of gcc-4.8](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.8/+publishinghistory)